# Center Div with aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css, centering, aspect-ratio

I need to Center a Div in the html viewport. It should be centered both, vertically and horizontally. But the Div should keep its aspect ratio (4/3) and have a minimum margin of 10px.

I made a Javascript:

```
function resizeWindow() {
 var wHeight = $(document).height() - 20;
 var wWidth = $(document).width() - 20;
 var gameStage = $("#gameStage");
 if ((wWidth / 4) * 3 <= wHeight) {
  gameStage.css("width", wWidth + "px");
  gameStage.css("height", ((wWidth / 4) * 3) + "px");
  gameStage.css("top", (wHeight - ((wWidth / 4) * 3)) / 2 + 9 + "px");
  gameStage.css("left", "10px");
 } else {
  gameStage.css("height", wHeight + "px");
  gameStage.css("width", ((wHeight / 3) * 4) + "px");
  gameStage.css("left", (wWidth - ((wHeight / 3) * 4)) / 2 + 9 + "px");
  gameStage.css("top", "10px");
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3sw06kvb/

But User, who disabled Javascript will not be able to use my website. And a solution with HTML/CSS should be faster(?).

My first Idea is to make a wrapper with

```
position: fixed 
top, left, bottom, right = 20px;.
```

But my problem is making a div centering vertically and horizontally while keeping its aspect ratio.

https://jsfiddle.net/xep2mf62/

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/kpLzp9kj/1/ (It's not the perfect result but..)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following in the CSS.
The new units in CSS3 `vh` and `vw` allows you to set the height depending on the size of the viewport. `height:100vh` will give the element a height that is equal to the height of the browser window.

***1vw = 1% of viewport width

1vh = 1% of viewport height***

```css
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width:100%;
      height:100vh;
    }
    .childdivision {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      height:50vw;
       width:90vw;
      border:2px solid #444;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="childdivision">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem is not just to center the div, but to keep his ratio (dynamically  width and height)

Comment: in that case a height can be set using `viewport` as the unit.

Comment: That's was I propose to @LittleSatan in the question's comment =)

Comment: If the browser is much more wider than higher, the div's height will become to big. It doesn't fit in the viewport anymore. 
In my javascript, the div will always be completly visible.

Answer (score 1):

Still JS, but simpler

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  resize();
};

function resize() {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
  var wrapperwidth = 1920;
  var wrapperheight = 1080;
  var vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  var vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
  var ratio = Math.min(vw / wrapperwidth, vh / wrapperheight);
  wrapper.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) scale(${ratio})`;
}

resize();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1919px;
  height: 1079px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

/* demo text (smiley face) */

.wrapper::after {
  content: ":)";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: "Roboto", 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```